# Error 500 when installing Wordpress

Tags: errors, installation

I logged into Cpanel, went to Wordpress install and configured all the setting as I normally do. When I hit install the bar showed up then stopped at 2% and then i got the popup ..."oops connection lost"

The bar stopped moving after that so i hit refresh and that's when i got this error,

Internal Server Error
500 Internal Error (ID 465869847991602)

It shows up everytime i go to Wordpress software installer.

Anyone knows hoe to solve this?

Comment: A WordPress installer in cPanel would be something offered by your host. Not something from WordPress itself. I suggest contacting your host for support.

Comment: Did you try turning it off and turning it back on again?

Comment: Softaculous is probably a better bet.